# How to set current time to some other time in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I am trying to set current time to some other time and whenever i try to access current time i need to get the new time. Suppose current time is 2 am in my local machine. But I want to change it to 10 am and current time should keep ticking from 10 am instead of 2 am whenever i access it.

Ex:

```
var x = new Date();
```

if you see x.getHours() fetches my local time which is 2 am
and every time it keeps ticking with 2 am as its base.

But I need to change it to 10 am so that my new Date() gives 10 am and keeps ticking every second based on that.

I do not want to use setInterval() for this purpose. I sure have solution with setInterval(). But the thing is I have multiple setIntervals and the other one is stopping from updating the time in the setInterval() where I am trying to update 10 am every second.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav2493/tw9Gf/) is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav2493/tw9Gf/)

Comment: Work in UTC, then adjust for timezone

Comment: Can you enlighten us on *why* you wish to do this?  Is it that you don't trust the user's clock?  Or are you trying to do something to handle time zones?  Or something else?  I have a feeling this is a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @MattJohnson it is just that i want to look through some data every second starting with 10 am irrespective of my machine time.

Comment: @CrazyNooB `10 am irrespective of my machine time`, This suggests to me that the computer would show the wrong time even before considering timezone, so instead of using time from local machine, fire a request to your server, get server time by looking at response header _Date_ and record difference between server time and machine time. Now you can modify your local reported time by the difference you recorded; resulting in a correct time (assuming server correct, local clock still right speed) regardless of how local machine was configured

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't change the system time from Javascript, not if it's running from the browser. You'd need a special environment, one with the ability to interface javascript and the operating system's API to do that. That's no simple thing and probably way out of the scope of the application you're working on.

I suggest you create a function/object with means to fetch the current date with an offset. Like this:

```
Foo = function () {};
Foo.prototype.offset = 8;
Foo.prototype.getDate = function () {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + this.offset);
    return date;
}
```

Now you can instantiate a `foo`, set the offset (8 by default) and work with it. When you need your offset hour you can just do:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = foo.getDate();
```

`bar` will not tick, but whenever you need the current date with an offset you may just use `Foo`'s `getDate` again.

**Edit:** In order to start from a fixed date, you can use the constructor like this:

```
Foo = function (baseDate) {
    this._date = baseDate;
    this._fetched = new Date();
}

Foo.prototype.getDate = function () {
    var now = new Date();
    var offset = now.getTime() - this._fetched.getTime();
    this._date.setTime(this._date.getTime() + offset);
    this._fetched = now;
    return this._date;
}
```

<strike>Notice that `now.getDay()` would return the day of the week, not the day of the month. Hence the `now.getDate()` up there.</strike> (Edited to use a base date instead of a fixed, hard-coded one).

Comment: I am checking your solution Renan. Will reply soon.

Comment: There, I fixed it with a functional version.

Comment: `Date.prototype.addHours=function(h){this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);return this};` :-)

Comment: @Bergi thanks :) ended up without modifying Date's prototype, though.

Comment: @Renan it sure is working. One more thing, I want it to tick with 10 am right from beginning, not taking into my local minutes and seconds into consideration. I mean it should keep ticking right from the first second of 10 AM. any thoughts on that..?

Comment: I am going to edit my answer to include that, one moment please.

Comment: There. I have written a version that starts from a fixed date.

Comment: @Renan how about i need something dynamic, I mean instead of 10 am it can be a user defined one...?

Comment: Then instead of setting a hard coded 10, receive the desired date in the constructor. Another edition to my answer.

Comment: @Renan instead of this._date it should be this.date, i believe, because it is throwin me error.

Comment: @Renan can we have that base date in integer, like if it is 1 pm it will be 13, so it wont be a date actually, but an integer.

Comment: This is going way beyond the scope of the original question - but if you can catch the idea of what I'm doing in my answer, you can adjust it to receive a number instead of a date, and then you can use that to make your own base date ;)

Comment: @Renan right i am changing it. Thanks for your prompt response. I am working on it.

Comment: @Renan worked like a charm. You made my day. Thanks for your quick and, to the point reply :)

Answer (score 6):

Using [TimeShift.js](https://github.com/plaa/TimeShift-js) this can be done fairly easy. in the beginning of your page include TimeShift.js and set the date explicitly. Shameless copy of its manual:

```
new Date().toString();                      // Original Date object
"Fri Aug 09 2013 23:37:42 GMT+0300 (EEST)"

Date = TimeShift.Date;                      // Overwrite Date object
new Date().toString();
"Fri Aug 09 2013 23:37:43 GMT+0300"

TimeShift.setTimezoneOffset(-60);           // Set timezone to GMT+0100 (note the sign)
new Date().toString();
"Fri Aug 09 2013 21:37:44 GMT+0100"

TimeShift.setTime(1328230923000);           // Set the time to 2012-02-03 01:02:03 GMT
new Date().toString();
"Fri Feb 03 2012 02:02:03 GMT+0100"

TimeShift.setTimezoneOffset(0);             // Set timezone to GMT
new Date().toString();
"Fri Feb 03 2012 01:02:03 GMT"

TimeShift.getTime();                        // Get overridden values
1328230923000
TimeShift.getTimezoneOffset();
0

TimeShift.setTime(undefined);               // Reset to current time
new Date().toString();
"Fri Aug 09 2013 20:37:45 GMT"

new Date().desc();                          // Helper method
"utc=Fri, 09 Aug 2013 20:37:46 GMT   local=Fri, 09 Aug 2013 20:37:46 GMT   offset=0"

new TimeShift.OriginalDate().toString();    // Use original Date object
"Fri Aug 09 2013 23:37:47 GMT+0300 (EEST)"
```

I think this is slightly better than writing a custom Date object/function (Foo) since this library doesn't require you to rewrite existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date(Thu Aug 08 2013 13:34:55 GMT+0200);
var h=today.setHours();
var m=today.setMinutes();
var s=today.setSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
{
i="0" + i;
}
return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

The long way:

```
var date = new Date();
var now = date.getTime();
now.setTime( 0,0,0,0 );
now.setMonth(4);
now.setDate(5);
now.setYear(2013);
```

The short way:

```
var date = new Date("Sat Apr 05 2013 19:30:13 GMT+0200 (IDT)");
```

Comment: What the OP needs is a date variable that self-updates every tick. Your `d` doesn't do that. Also notice that `n` is a number and doesn't have the `Date` type methods. Try that code in your browser's console.

Answer (score -2):

Simple:

```
var x = new Date("Fri Aug 09 2013 19:30:13 GMT+0300 (IDT)");
```

Now the date of x is two days ahead (09/08/2013)

Comment: Only problem is that `x` doesn't update its time every tick like the OP needs. Do read the question again.